# Form tag is not well formed (control Id)

Tags: asp.net

Hi can anyone help me regarding my problem. I assigned a dynamic Id into the ID property of an image control. The problem is I got an error saying "form tag is not well formed". I replaced the double quote into a single or removed those quotes but I got the same error. How can I resolved this issue? By the way I used c# language.

```
<img ID="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Make this

```
<img ID="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>" runat="server" />
```

to this:

```
<img ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' runat="server" />
```

Update: apparently it's indeed not possible to do this. I tried in a test application further with both the html image and Image server control. After thinking a bit further, and taking some coffee, it kind of makes sense that an ID cannot be set as such. How would you set properties on something without an ID in codebehind?

An alternative way what you can do however is this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phTest"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in codebehind:

```
HtmlImage image = new HtmlImage();
image.ID = "SomeRandomId";
image.Src = "urltosomeimage";

phTest.Controls.Add(image);
```

Comment: Is this line hosted in some gridview or panel or other control?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem and I solved it like this:

```
<img ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' runat="server" />
```

The reason for this is that the expression between <%# %> cannot be evaluated if it is not in single quotes.

Comment: Are you sure you tried this? Making that change should be ok.

Can you post other code from your page in case incorrect markup above this line is causing the error?

Comment: Try `<img ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' />`

Comment: I changed the control into a server control, this was the error occured  "The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" /> . "

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<asp:img ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' runat="server" />
```

or try to remove the runat="server" since your img tag is not a server control

Comment: same error, if I removed the runat="server", I can't access the control to disabled it in code behind.

Comment: The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: <asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" /> . this was the error occured

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.0 set `ClientIDMode=Static` or change ID not in markup but in code-behind.

And use  instead of  if you need access it from code-behind.