# Server Tag is not well formed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before adding style to paragraph it was working fine but if i add style i am getting error like server tag is not well formed.please check out my code

```
<p 
    title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>' 
    id="P1" 
    runat="server" 
    style="top:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Tops") %>px; left:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lefts") %>px; font-size:15px; color:White;">
</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form tag is not well formed (control Id)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178157/form-tag-is-not-well-formed-control-id)

Answer (score 5):

on server bound controls, if you want to use <%#whatever%> inside of a property they must have single quotes instead of double. ie:

```
<asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("myvalue")%>' />
```

or

```
<p id="p1" runat="server" style='background:<%#Eval("color")%>;'>stuff here</p>
```

Comment: No, actually i'm using paragraph inside that i'm using style for thati'm bingding is it possible to bind.

Comment: right, but the paragraph tag is server bound since it has a runat=server.

Comment: I added a sample with a paragraph tag

Comment: If i give in sigle quotes i am not able read the values , if i remove runnat server its working fine .

Answer (score 1):

Just use single quotes around your style tag so you avoid the collision with the double quotes in the Eval part.

```
style='top:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Tops") %>px; left:%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lefts") %>px; font-size:15px; color:White;">'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<p 
    title='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>' 
    id="P1" 
    runat="server" 
    style='top:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Tops") %>px; left:<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lefts") %>px; font-size:15px; color:White;'>
</p>
```